# How to Enable/Disable a button in VB.Net depending on value?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I need to have my button disabled while `dzien=0`, and enabled while `dzien >0`.

When I launch the application, it doesn't matter if day is 0 or 102938129038, button is still disabled. What's wrong with my code?

```
Imports System.IO.IsolatedStorage
Partial Public Class Page1
Inherits PhoneApplicationPage
Private dzien As Integer
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings("dzien") = dzien
    Try
        dzien = CInt(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings("dzien"))
    Catch ex As KeyNotFoundException
        dzien = 0
    End Try
    If dzien = 0 Then
        dzien = dzien + 1
    End If
    NavigationService.Navigate(New Uri("/2.xaml", UriKind.Relative))
End Sub
Private Sub Class_1_loaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    If dzien = 0 Then
        Button2.IsEnabled = False
    Else
        Button2.IsEnabled = True
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    dzien = dzien + 1

    NavigationService.Navigate(New Uri("/2.xaml", UriKind.Relative))
End Sub
End Class
```

I'm not sure if

```
If dzien = 0 Then
    dzien = dzien + 1
End If
```

works well
and

```
dzien = dzien + 1
```

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF? (I imagine WPF due to the `RoutedEvent` parameter.)  And when is `Class_1_loaded` called?  Have you wired this up as an eventhandler somewhere?  Also, when is `dzien` set?  Hav eyou used a breakpoint to confirm the value when your code runs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Private Sub Class_1_loaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
If dzien = 0 Then
   Button2.Enabled = False
Else 
   Button2.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: still same. But I think the matter isn't in button enabling/disabling. 

Look on description, I uploaded all code.

Comment: What is the button's default set to, enabled or disabled? Are you sure you've connected everything up properly?

Comment: as default it's enabled. I think it's ok. When my page loads, button automatically turns off. But when I want to press another button, that will activate this one, it doesn't work.

Comment: I think the problem is in 
If dzien = 0 Then
    dzien = dzien + 1
End If
 and in 
dzien = dzien + 1

Comment: Not completely. Now increasing value works and button works. BUT, my first button has 3 options, increasing value, moving to next page and saving variable. On the next page, where this button leads, my variable is still 0. It changes to 1 on the first one (up), but when it moves to next one it "resets" value to default (0) despite of saving it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but if `.ENABLED` and `.ISENABLED` are not the same, I think that is the problem...